# VT-x enabled in BIOS, but disabled in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bios, virtualization, vt-x

I'm tryting to run NOX app player but show warning message Virtualization is off and in task manager the vt-x is indeed disabled.

I already enabled it in BIOS and i don't have AVAST antivirus to block it as I saw in other posts.

I already tried several things, like disable it, reboot, enable and reboot again, nothing worked.

Any help I would appreciate!

EDIT: I only had vt-x enabled and forgot to enable Intel Virtualization in CPU options. Problem Solved!

Comment: But I only have Windows Defender, how can be a security software problem?
And you don't know how to solve it?

Comment: Could you please tell me how?

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Your edit actually was the answer for me too! could you mark my answer correct? I'm sure we're not the only two that will not know to check in the CPU configuration section.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Hyper-V enabled by any chance ?
If Hyper-V is enabled, other applications can not use full virtualisation-features (Virtualbox, VMWare Player/Workstation) and are of limited functionality (only able to use 1 core for example).

Check if this is enabled and disable it if you wish to use another virtualisation software.

Comment: I had Hyper-V already disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You must enable **Hyper-V** feature as well if you are running **Windows 10**.
In the search bar of Windows 10 type **"Turn Windows Features on or off"**
and make sure the option "Hyper-V" is checked.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In addition to enabling virtualization (vt-x) in the system agent configuration, you also have to enable virtualization in the CPU configuration section. I missed that part too!